# deleteByField query method is failing though table has values

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my spring boot app I'm using query method `deleteByCollectioId(someValue)` (where CollectionId is the field name) to delete all entries present in my DB with given value.

**Code**

```
  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  void deleteByCollectionId(Long collectionId);
```

This code worked fine for many days but recently few times this started giving me an error saying

> Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1

I am not able to find root cause as this error is not reproducable most of the times. Is there anything wrong in Entity Class or Code?

**Entity Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ToString(doNotUseGetters = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "myCollection")
public class Collection {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "auto_inc_id")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "auto_inc_id", strategy = "increment")
  private Long id;


  @Column(name = "collection_id")
  @JsonProperty(value = "collection_id")
  private Long collectionId;

  ..
  ..
  ..

}
```

**Note**: Here `collectionId` is not unique across multiple rows, there can be multiple rows with same `collectionId`

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and mariaDB? If not please dont add irrelevant tags. They are designed to attract the correct audience that are interested and/or capable in that subject. Not to just gather a crowd of villagers with pitchforks and torches

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that collection ID is not unique across all collections? Your primary key seems to be `id`. How do you guarantee collection ID is unique?

You may want to implement your own `equals/hash` method.

Also you don't need `@Modifying` annotation. It's only used when you use the Query annotation. [Spring Data Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html)

Comment: CollectionId is unique across all collections. But the table represents all products under collection, so within the table there can be multiple rows with same collectionId

Comment: What are TableConstants.GENERATOR and TableConstants.STRATEGY set to?

Comment: I feel like there is more to it than what you are sharing, like "Collection" has a relation with another entity. Keep in mind, that when you do "deleteByCollectionId", JPA will do a "select * from myCollection where collection_id = ?" and then executes "delete from myCollection where id = ?" for all IDs that it finds, so if it finds 10 rows with that collection ID, it will issue 10 delete statements. It is possible that delete by ID is some how attempting to delete more than one row. Perhaps the constraints were relaxed at one point. Perhaps you want to try using native query in this case.

Comment: Generator and Strategy  are used to autoIncrement ID, updated the question to show actual values

Comment: So you are saying if Collection table has 10 rows with collectionId as X, then JPA will issue 10 delete statements, because of which it is failing

Comment: Yes, 10 delete statements by "id", not by "CollectionID", and since "id" is the key for a row, it expects 1 row to be "updated", meaning deleted. But the row count is 2, so there are two rows with the same "id" in the myCollection table. That's my guess from what I see.

Comment: Yeah, checked in DB there are 2 entries with same id for some records

Comment: Is this because of Id generation method I'm using?

`@Id `
`@Column(name = "id")`
`@GeneratedValue(generator = "auto_inc_id")`
`@GenericGenerator(name = "auto_inc_id", strategy = "increment")`

Comment: You should not use "increment" strategy. It is not thread or cluster safe. This is probably why you have multiple entries with the same id. In fact, I think this was removed from later versions of Hibernate. My suggestion is to use a sequence, and use JPA annotation (not Hibernate) to point to the sequence. Also you should fix the duplicate ID manually, otherwise the problem will persist.